# Using FME, Is there a way to transfer Metadata from an SDE FeatureClass to a Shapefile (shp.xml)

Tags: shapefile, enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, metadata

Is there a way to transfer, using FME, the metadata from an SDE featureclass to a shapefile?

Comment: Change the Feature Read Mode to Metadata Mode http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Writing-geodatabase-metadata-to-an-xml-file

Comment: I did that. It just won't attach itself to the shapafile.

Comment: Take note of http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/FME-and-Metadata shapefile_name.xml needs to be written out with a different writer (text with .xml works)